# Setting QgsVectorLayer created from CSV in editing mode with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, csv, editing, qgsvectorlayer

I'm working on QGIS 3.28.10 and I want to create a `QgsVectorLayer` from a CSV file with PyQGIS script, but the resulting layer is not editable. Does anyone know how to set this layer as editable?

My script:

```py
file = 'path_to_csv_file' 
uri = (
    "file:///{}?"
    "&delimiter={}"
    "&xField={}"
    "&yField={}"
    "&crs={}"
    "&decimal").format(file, ";", "X", "Y", "EPSG:4326")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
layer.startEditing()
layer.isEditable() # Returns False
```

Comment: Delimited text layers can not be directly edited in QGIS, not via pyqgis nor gui. See: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers. You will need to convert to a format which supports editing such as GeoPackage or Shapefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A delimited text layer is not editable in QGIS by default. You have to export it as a spatial format like GeoPackage, ShapeFile etc.

You can check what capabilities a layer has using the [`capabilitiesString()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a26e6e3cab8c961c44786392df73909fe) method of the data provider.

```py
iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().capabilitiesString()
```

You get the following result for a CSV source:

```
'Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID, Curved Geometries'
```

And this result for GeoPackage:

```
'Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Rename Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Create Attribute Indexes, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries, Transactions, Curved Geometries'
```